# Mi método envía un archivo correcto y un archivo dañado ¿como enviar solo el archivo bueno?

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Tengo un problema con mi código el cual genera bien el archivo PDF y lo envía al correo electrónico pero al momento que se vuelve a enviar otro correo este envía el archivo pdf bien pero adjunta otro archivo pdf que esta dañado y con el mismo nombre ya elimine el archivo con File.Delete(); y sigue enviando el mismo archivo dañado y el bueno cada vez que se envia un 2do, 3ro, etc.
este es mi código.

```
    public void enviarCorreo(string emisor, string password, string mensaje, string asunto, string destinatario, string ruta)
    {
        try
        {
        correos.To.Clear();
        correos.Body = "";
        correos.Subject = "";
        correos.Body = mensaje;
        correos.Subject = asunto;
        correos.IsBodyHtml = true;
        correos.To.Add(destinatario.Trim());

        if (ruta.Equals("") == false)
        {

            correos.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(GetStreamFile(ruta), Path.GetFileName(ruta), "application/pdf"));
            //System.Net.Mail.Attachment archivo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ruta);
            //correos.Attachments.Add(archivo);
        }
        if (ruta == "C:\\Reportes\\FormatoVisita" + cuenta + ".pdf")
        {
            correos.From = new MailAddress(emisor);
            envios.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emisor, password);

            envios.Host = "mail.ihscompany.com";//"smtp.live.com";
            envios.Port = 587;
            envios.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { return true; };

            envios.Send(correos);
            MessageBox.Show("El mensaje fue enviado correctamente");
        }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "No se pudo enviar el correo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }                 
        }



    private void tsAutorizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//problemas con el correo 
    {
        //try
        //{
        if (dgvVisitas.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("¿Desea Autorizar la visita de " + txtNombre.Text + "?", "Administrador", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Base.ActualizarAutorizacion(Convert.ToInt32(dgvVisitas.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                bs.FormatoVisita(lblFechaVis, lblCliente, lblPlanta, lblDirección, Convert.ToInt32(dgvVisitas.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                bs.FormatoVisitaVendedor(lblNombre, lblPuesto, lblFirma, lblEmpleado, dgvVisitas.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                bs.BuscarContactoVisitas(dgvContactos, Convert.ToInt32(dgvVisitas.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
                lblFecha.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
                bs.FormatoVisitaGerente(lblCorreo, lblPassword, txtVendedor.Text);

                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(panel2.Width, panel2.Height, panel2.CreateGraphics());
                panel2.DrawToBitmap(b, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, panel2.Width, panel2.Height));
                using (Document doc = new Document())
                {

                    iTextSharp.text.Image i = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(b, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        cuenta++;
                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Reportes\FormatoVisita"+cuenta+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
                        ruta = "C:\\Reportes\\FormatoVisita"+cuenta+".pdf";
                        doc.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(panel2.Size.Width + doc.LeftMargin + doc.RightMargin, panel2.Size.Height + doc.TopMargin + doc.BottomMargin));
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(i);
                        doc.Close();
                        enviarCorreo(lblCorreo.Text, lblPassword.Text, "Autorizaci&oacute;n de visita de " + lblNombre.Text, "Autorizaci&oacute;n de visita de " + lblNombre.Text, "sistemas@ihscompany.com", ruta);//contabilidad2@ihscompany.com


                }
                //ruta = "";
                if (tipo == "Administrador")
                {
                    bs.ADMBuscarVisitas2(dgvVisitas);
                }
                else
                {
                    bs.BuscarVisitas(dgvVisitas, txtVendedor.Text);
                }
                bs.auto(txtBusca, txtVendedor.Text);
            }

            //}
            //catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

Comment: Por favor comparte un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de reestablecer todas las propiedades de la varialble `correos` cada vez que se invoca la función, elimina esta variable como global e instanciala dentro del mismo método, por ejemplo:

```
public void enviarCorreo(string emisor, string password, string mensaje, string asunto, string destinatario, string ruta)
{
    try
    {
    MailMessage correos = new MailMessage();
    correos.Body = mensaje;
    correos.Subject = asunto;
    correos.IsBodyHtml = true;
    correos.To.Add(destinatario.Trim());

    // ENTIENDO QUE ESTE IF SE PUEDE ELIMINAR Y AGREGAR LA LINEA DE CODIGO DENTRO DEL OTRO IF
    if (ruta.Equals("") == false)
    {

        correos.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(GetStreamFile(ruta), Path.GetFileName(ruta), "application/pdf"));
        //System.Net.Mail.Attachment archivo = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ruta);
        //correos.Attachments.Add(archivo);
    }
    if (ruta == "C:\\Reportes\\FormatoVisita" + cuenta + ".pdf")
    {
        correos.From = new MailAddress(emisor);
        envios.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emisor, password);

        envios.Host = "mail.ihscompany.com";//"smtp.live.com";
        envios.Port = 587;
        envios.EnableSsl = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        { return true; };

        envios.Send(correos);
        MessageBox.Show("El mensaje fue enviado correctamente");
    }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "No se pudo enviar el correo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }                 
    }
```

Comment: Gracias al parecer si era problema con la propiedad de correos, gracias por la ayuda